# Qos(qWAVE API) for Multicast strange behavior

Tags: sockets, multicast, qos

In Windows7 64bit OS, I use qWAVE api to set the DSCP value for outgoing packets with a normal traffic udp and it work fine.

But , I 'm trying to do the same thing for a multicast traffic, but it looks strange!!

The code logical flow like this:

1. Create a socket and join an multicast group
2. Create another socket, the qWAVE report error when add the socket to it

In one PC, run step #1 will let step #2 failed in 10~20 seconds.
I guess the issue due to qWAVE implementation, I'm not sure.  Thanks if any tips.

Below is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <qos2.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"Qwave.lib")

#define GREOUP_IP "231.31.31.31"
#define LOCAL_IP "192.168.1.106" // change to local ip

int testQOS() {
  WSADATA WSAData;
  DWORD err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &WSAData); 
  if (err) { 
    printf("WSAStartup Failed (%d) Exiting\n", err); 
    exit(err); 
  }
  SOCKET hSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
  if (hSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) { 
    printf("\"Socket\" failed with error %d\n", GetLastError()); 
    return 1; 
  }
  SOCKADDR_IN addr_dest;
  addr_dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr_dest.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(GREOUP_IP);
  addr_dest.sin_port = htons(333);

  //QOS
    HANDLE m_hQOSHandle = NULL;
    DWORD m_QOSLastFlowId = 0;
    if (m_hQOSHandle == NULL) {
        QOS_VERSION ver = {1, 0}; //major, minor
        if (!QOSCreateHandle(&ver, &m_hQOSHandle)) {
      printf("Could not initialize the QOS/QWave subsystem (error %d).\n", GetLastError()); 
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (!QOSAddSocketToFlow(m_hQOSHandle, hSocket, (PSOCKADDR)&addr_dest, QOSTrafficTypeVoice,
                                                    QOS_NON_ADAPTIVE_FLOW, &m_QOSLastFlowId)) {
        m_QOSLastFlowId = 0;
    printf("Could not set QOS parameters on socket (error  %d)\n.", GetLastError()); 
        return 1;
    }

  shutdown(hSocket, SD_BOTH);
  closesocket(hSocket);

  QOSRemoveSocketFromFlow(m_hQOSHandle, hSocket, m_QOSLastFlowId, 0);
  QOSCloseHandle(m_hQOSHandle);

  WSACleanup();

  return 0;
}

int testMultiGroup() {
  WSADATA WSAData;
  DWORD err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &WSAData); 
  if (err) { 
    printf("WSAStartup Failed (%d) Exiting\n", err); 
    exit(err); 
  }
  SOCKET hSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
  if (hSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) { 
    printf("\"Socket\" failed with error %d\n", GetLastError());
    return 1; 
  }

  SOCKADDR_IN addr_dest;
  addr_dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr_dest.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(GREOUP_IP);
  addr_dest.sin_port = htons(333);

  struct ip_mreq mreq;
  mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(GREOUP_IP);
    mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr(LOCAL_IP);
  // comment below line, the code will works
  setsockopt(hSocket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char*)&mreq, sizeof(mreq));

  sendto(hSocket, "test", 4, 0, (sockaddr*)&addr_dest,sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));

  shutdown(hSocket, SD_BOTH);
  closesocket(hSocket);

  WSACleanup();

  return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  // join an IP group membership
  // comment below method will pass the test
  // if test is failed: wait 10~20 sec or change GREOUP_IP after comment below method
  //                    will fix the test
  //if(testMultiGroup()) return 1;

  // try to add socket to QOS flow
  if(testQOS()) return 1;

  return 0;
}
```